# C# Use list defined in method in other methods

Tags: c#, list, methods

First of all I'm quite a beginner in working with C# so please be kind :D

I am currently working on a project where I need to get data in the form of various lists from an API and then use it further.
Getting the data is generally not a problem. The whole thing happens in a method 1.
However, I now have to use the contents of these lists in a method 2 and I am absolutely at a loss as to how I can implement the whole thing without carrying out method 1, in which the list is filled, again in method 2.
Maybe someone can help me and tell me how I can use lists that were filled in method 1 in method 2 without calling and executing method 1 in method 2.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: A) let method1 returns list so you can pass it to method2... B) method1 can change object state (store list in field) and method2 can use it...

Comment: It would be better to take some c# course... We don't know if you know how to return value from method, do you know what are fields or properties or do you know how to pass parameters or what are variables scopes... This is not  good place for learning basics

Comment: Store the list in a field, i.e., a variable at class level, outside of a method instead of using a local variable, i.e., a variable declared in a method.

Comment: @Selvin I do know those things. Maybe my question was a bit unclear. Ill edit it and maybe youll understand my problem afterwards :)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes describes the proper solution. Create a class with three (or more) members, `Method1` and `Method2` like you have, but with also one or more fields (class-level variables) that contain your initialized lists. Now Method1 can add items to the list(s) and Method2 can consume those items. If you want more information, you will need to improve your question (particularly by adding your code) so that we can refer to your code in our answers

Answer (score 0):

Store the list in a field, i.e., a variable at class level, outside of a method instead of using a local variable, i.e., a variable declared in a method.

```cs
private readonly List<int> _list = new();

private void Method1()
{
    _list.Add(2);
    _list.Add(3);
    _list.Add(5);
    _list.Add(7);
}

private void Method2()
{
    foreach (int i in _list) {
        Console.Writeline(i);
    }
}
```